# Meaning of a varaible for calculating the partial derviative of MSE cost function

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, loss-functions, gradient-descent, derivative

The equation to find the partial derivative of a cost function with respect to a parameter `θj` is given in the book '*Hands on Machine Learning with scikit-learn, keras and tensorflow* ':

[image]

- *m* = number of instances in the dataset
- **x** = input vector for the prediction
- *y* = label for the input vector

I am not able to understand what the last scalar `x(i)j` means. Could someone please tell me what the variable means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context you have provided, my reading is that $x^{(i)}_j$ is the $j$-th element of the $i$-th input vector $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$, where there are $i = 1,..., m$ training instances.

---

**Addressing comments.**

In response to:

> So in the case where $j = 1$, that is, $\theta_j = \theta_1$, then $x^{(i)}_j$ would be the 1st element of $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$.

Yes you are entirely correct.

And in response to:

> E.g : If $\mathbf{x}^{(i)} = [1,2,3,4,5]$ and $\theta_j = \theta_1$ then $x^{(i)}_j$ = 2 (considering 0 to be the first index).

This is just my view, but my personal preference, and also advice, is to make a distinction between formal "mathematics-indexing" which you see in mathematics in print, and implementational "Python-indexing". This is to avoid confusion.

In the case of mathematics-indexing, which is the convention for indexing vectors like $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$ in print, then in your case $j = 1, ... 5$. In this case, then in your example $x^{(i)}_1 = 1$, i.e. the *first element of the vector* $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$.

In the case of (what I am assuming to be) Python-indexing, which is what you will need for implementation, then $j = 0, ..., 4$. For your example, under this convention, then you are correct, $x^{(i)}_1 = 2$. Having now checked the book this is correct, Geron is using $j = 0, ..., n$ to index $(n+1)$ elements of the vector $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$.

Comment: So if θj = θ1, then x(i)j would be the 1st element of x(i). E.g : If  x(i) = [1,2,3,4,5] and θj = θ1 then x(i)j = 2 (considering 0 to be the first index).

Comment: Thank you, that helps.

Comment: Having now looked at the book - you are correct on both counts, the author is using using $j= 0, ..., n$ to index the $(n+1)$ elements of $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$.

Comment: Sorry, but could I ask a small follow-up question? If θj = 5 then should the jth element in θ also be 5? E.g - If on the left hand side θj=  θ3 = 5 then should the θ on the right-hand-side of the equation be [θ0, θ1, θ2, 5, θ4, θ5, θ6]?

Comment: I will use a new response to answer your new question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517820/meaning-of-%ce%b8j-in-equation-for-partial-derivative-of-mse and address this final comment in the new response